# websockets not working client side from windows 7

Tags: java, websocket, atmosphere

We are using [Atmosphere 2.4.2](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) for websocket connections. The server application resides on cloud (linux OS). From one of the client boxes (windows 7 SP1), websockets is not opening up.
Websockets are working from almost all other client boxes.

1. None of the browsers are able to send/ receive messages on this windows box.
2. A quick test to http://websocketstest.com/   -> connect -> send . works fine.
3. Tried turning off antivirus and firewall did not help.

Any ideas what may be blocking on this box.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there were two issues.

1. The etc/hosts file has extra entries. Because of which websockets were not upgraded. Still don't know why this should be a cause.
2. When using vpn, Some of the vpn proxies are old and do not support header upgrade. this is also possible when multiple proxy hops are present
   https://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers
3. The work around is to use SSE (server side events). With Atmosphere its few lines change. IE by default does not support SSE. Just in case.